# noclassdeffounderror with "com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32" and "org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32" while running through maven/selenium

Tags: maven, selenium, pom.xml

As i am running sample application using maven i am getting following error.please have a look and guide ,following are the logs and pom.xml.

though tests runs successfully that is browser got opened as expected but build failure happens

```
public class GoogleTest{

   @Test
    public void testGoogle()
    {
       //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\dilu316\\Downloads\\selenium workspace\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
       //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\dilu316\\Downloads\\selenium workspace\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
       WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }


}

The following error logs happen:  
-------------------------------------------------------

 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.testing.GoogleTest
1489310484173   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:34551
1489310484869   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\dilu316\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.QqB2wW3EaREi
1489310484886   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args []
1489310484895   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:54584
1489310487924   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 54584
Mar 12, 2017 2:51:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1489310494254   Marionette      INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
[Child 384] WARNING: pipe error: 232: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 512
[Child 384] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2143
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.268 sec <<< FAILURE!
testGoogle(com.testing.GoogleTest)  Time elapsed: 11.218 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.getProcessId(ProcessUtils.java:184)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$200(UnixProcess.java:200)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:198)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:94)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:661)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
        at com.testing.GoogleTest.testGoogle(GoogleTest.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 54 more

Running com.testing.YahooTest
1489310494556   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:43880
1489310495021   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\dilu316\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.1o7a0AEkUuwY
1489310495025   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args []
1489310495033   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:54615
1489310496713   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 54615
Mar 12, 2017 2:51:40 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1489310509473   Marionette      INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
[Child 7608] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2143
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.319 sec <<< FAILURE!
testYahoo(com.testing.YahooTest)  Time elapsed: 15.315 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32 
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.getProcessId(ProcessUtils.java:184)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$200(UnixProcess.java:200)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:198)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:94)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:661)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
        at com.testing.YahooTest.testYahoo(YahooTest.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Results :

Tests in error:
  testGoogle(com.testing.GoogleTest): com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32
  testYahoo(com.testing.YahooTest): org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 29.684 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-12T14:51:50+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project MyMavenProject: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\dilu316\Documents\maven\MyMavenProject\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

C:\Users\dilu316\Documents\maven\MyMavenProject>
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyMavenProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MyMavenProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I see you did not include the selenium maven plugin in the build, is it intended?

Comment: actually with selenium maven plugin ,browsers didnt open and i got same noclasdeffounderror : org/openqa/selenium/logging/NeedsLocalLogs

Comment: Perhaps you could show your config in that case?

Comment: which config please guide me i ll share.

Comment: The pom.xml with the selenium maven plugin, your test cases that fail would be a huge help as here we are in the dark, we have no idea what your tests do.

Comment: yeah added the sample code

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your pom file, your probably running `mvn test` (am I correct?) and in your selenium dependency you need to add `<scope>test</scope>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Elaboration**: the scope in a maven dependency dictates in what step (plugin:goal) the dependency will be used (e.g. what to use as the classpath). Since you're running tests and these dependencies are of the test phase you need to specify that. Now, your error says you're missing a dependency (it can't find some class), That's because the dependencies in the `test` scope are not transitive - meaning the class `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32` which is a dependency for Selenium as I saw in your dependency tree won't be resolved to your local maven repository.

**Solution**: Add a maven dependency for the missing class (which is in the package `net.java.dev.jna.platform`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yeah i used both mvn test and mvn package but same error is coming

Comment: `mvn test` is the correct way.. did you try adding the `scope`?

Comment: yeah but i think those jars are missing like "com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32 " and "org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32 "

Comment: @Moshisho It would be great if you could please help elaborate as to how does adding a `test` `<scope>` fix this problem ?

Comment: @HaraMohapatra - Can you please help do the following ? Open up a command prompt and run `mvn dependency:tree > deps.txt` and share the contents of `deps.txt` by putting it up on gist.github.com ? On first sight it looks like you have a dependency issue, wherein the "net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform" and "net.java.dev.jna:jna" are not perhaps downloaded properly. The error will come only if the "jna-platform" library is missing from your CLASSPATH

Comment: Hi Krihnan please find the link below https://gist.github.com/haramohapatra/b95fd2cad22d335d0af6765cedd99d81

Answer (score 0):

Use `driver.close();` instead. I had the same issue.